# Angular 8 : Lazy Loaded js files are not shown in Visual Studio Solution Explorer

Tags: angular, deployment, angular8, visual-studio-2019, angular-lazyloading

I have created the code for implementing Lazy loading in my app.

I can see the js files for lazyloaded modules in my **DIST** folder as below

But these files are **not visible in Solution Explorer in Visual Studio** for checkin.
Due to which the application is not loading lazy loaded modules in production server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the issue was that when i looked into Source Control Explorer the files were not added. So i needed to add them manually and then those file started appearing.

I was gigging in so much for this since last few days.